# sap.m.Select ignores sapUiSizeCozy in headerContent of ObjectPageLayout

Tags: css, xml, sapui5

Edit:
Bug report [Bug Report](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3348)  on github

Situation:
I am writing an app with the ObjectPageLayout.
In the header content I have a sap.m.Select and a sap.m.MultiComboBox with a reset button each.
I want to have them in the header, since they filter all Diagramms and Tabels of the diffrent tabs.
I set my css class as it is discribed in the [Workthrough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh6es.png).
When the style is set to compact mode due to the device type everything is fine.

Problem:
When the css class is cozy the select still has the compact style.
The MultiComboBox and buttons and everything else take the cozy style.
--> it looks really bad

Does anyone have an idea, why the select doesn't have the cozy style aswell?

I even tryed hard setting the css style in the XML, but it doesn't work.
If I change the css class of the MultiComboBox or the buttons it works,
but I dont want to always have everything on compact just because the select cannot go on cozy...

[image]
[image]
[image]

To replicate the problem you can just create a new project (UI5 Version 1.71) in the webide and replace the view with mine:

```
<mvc:View
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
        xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
        xmlns="sap.uxap"
        xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
        xmlns:m="sap.m"
        xmlns:f="sap.f"
        controllerName="TEST.TestingSelects.controller.Home"
        height="100%"
    >

    <ObjectPageLayout
        id="ObjectPageLayout"
        enableLazyLoading="true"
        useIconTabBar="true"
        showTitleInHeaderContent="false"
    >
        <headerTitle>
            <ObjectPageHeader
                id="headerForTest"
                objectTitle="{i18n>home.title}"
            >
            </ObjectPageHeader>
        </headerTitle>
        <headerContent>


            <m:VBox>
                <m:HBox>
                    <m:Select
                        id="idStoreSelect"
                        selectedKey="{homeModel>/storeSelectKey}"
                        change="onStoreSelectChange"
                        items=""
                    >
                        <core:Item
                            key=""
                            text=""
                        />
                    </m:Select>

                    <m:Button
                        icon="sap-icon://redo"
                        press="onResetStoreButtonPress"
                        tooltip="{i18n>home.store.redo.tooltip}"
                        type="Transparent"
                    />
                </m:HBox>

                <m:HBox>
                    <m:MultiComboBox
                        id="idCatMCB"
                        selectedKeys=""
                        selectionChange="onCatMBCChange"
                        items=""
                    >
                        <core:Item
                            key=""
                            text=""
                        />
                    </m:MultiComboBox>

                    <m:Button
                        icon="sap-icon://redo"
                        press="onResetCatButtonPress"
                        tooltip="{i18n>home.cat.redo.tooltip}"
                        type="Transparent"
                    />
                </m:HBox>
            </m:VBox>



        </headerContent>
        <sections>
            <ObjectPageSection title="2014 Goals Plan">
                <subSections>
                    <ObjectPageSubSection title=" ">
                        <blocks>
                            <m:Button
                                icon="sap-icon://redo"
                                press="onResetCatButtonPress"
                                tooltip="{i18n>home.cat.redo.tooltip}"
                                type="Transparent"
                            />
                        </blocks>
                    </ObjectPageSubSection>
                </subSections>
            </ObjectPageSection>

            <ObjectPageSection title="Personal">
                <subSections>
                    <ObjectPageSubSection title="Connect">
                        <blocks>
                            <m:Button
                                icon="sap-icon://redo"
                                press="onResetCatButtonPress"
                                tooltip="{i18n>home.cat.redo.tooltip}"
                                type="Transparent"
                            />
                        </blocks>
                    </ObjectPageSubSection>

                    <ObjectPageSubSection id="paymentSubSection" title="Payment information">
                        <blocks>
                            <m:Button
                                icon="sap-icon://redo"
                                press="onResetCatButtonPress"
                                tooltip="{i18n>home.cat.redo.tooltip}"
                                type="Transparent"
                            />
                        </blocks>
                    </ObjectPageSubSection>
                </subSections>
            </ObjectPageSection>
        </sections>
    </ObjectPageLayout>
</mvc:View>
```

Code of select when hard setting css style:

```
<m:Select
    id="idStoreSelect"
    class="sapUiSizeCozy"
    selectedKey="{homeModel>/storeSelectKey}"
    change="onStoreSelectChange"
    items=""
>
  
    <core:Item
        key=""
        text=""
    />
</m:Select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP fixed the [UI5 bug](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3348) with the version 1.95 ([commit `4c7fffe`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/4c7fffecac0e81485aca9fbb97f6ae7a82521bc8)).
Here you can see, that the `sap.m.Select` no longer has its own height set in the `ObjectPageHeaderContent` but applies the height according to the density class:

### UI5 ≥ 1.95

[image: Select within ObjectPageLayout header since UI5 1.95 - sapUiSizeCozy]
[image: Select within ObjectPageLayout header since UI5 1.95 - sapUiSizeCompact]

### UI5 ≤ 1.94

[image: Select within ObjectPageLayout header until UI5 1.94 - sapUiSizeCozy]
[image: Select within ObjectPageLayout header until UI5 1.94 - sapUiSizeCompact]

---

Screenshots from: https://plnkr.co/edit/gTxIx9BvTChZovBZ?preview

Answer (score 0):

To fix the width of the `Select` you can add the aggregation `layoutData`

```xml
<m:layoutData>
    <m:FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
</m:layoutData>
```

To fix the height of the `Button` you need to set the content density (as described in the official [Walkthrough (Step 37)](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d935dbf196d34997bf1ac42ac3e81579)).

Basically you provide a method in your `Component.js` which returns the correct density (and don't forget to import `"sap/ui/Device"` at the top!)

```js
getContentDensityClass : function () {
    if (!this._sContentDensityClass) {
        if (!Device.support.touch) {
            this._sContentDensityClass = "sapUiSizeCompact";
        } else {
            this._sContentDensityClass = "sapUiSizeCozy";
        }
    }
    return this._sContentDensityClass;
}
```

Then in the controller of your root view (defined in `manifest.json` > `sap.ui5` > `rootView`) you can call this method

```js
onInit: function() {
    this.getView().addStyleClass(
        this.getOwnerComponent().getContentDensityClass()
    );
}
```

I put together a small sample:
https://plnkr.co/edit/h1JZiyYrWLmuck46

Comment: it isnt working with the layout data for me. But I wasn't able to recreate the problem in your plnkr.... i added the layout data both in the my actual app and in my recreation in the webide. In both the problem is still the same

Comment: i am searching for differences in your example and the auto generated files of the webide. MB i find my mistake there. but so far no luck

Comment: Do you have some secret custom css? Do you have a different theme? Are you testing on a tablet/phone (bigger inputs)? My main focus with this fix was for the width. Height shouldn't have been a problem in the first place.

Comment: In your screenshot you are hovering the HBoxes. The select/multi combo box would be way more interesting.

Comment: I am using the fiori 3 theme. No css. Heigth of HBox 44px, of Select 28px of combobox 38px. I am aware it shouldnt happen, it doesn't outside of the objectPageLayout headerContent. Only in this specific setup. I just can't find out what the cause is. As said before i can replicate the problem by creating a project in the webide from template and only changing the sapui5 version to 1.71 in the wizard and then replacing the generated xml view with the posted code

Comment: i tried to put all files of webide in a plnkr, only changing the source in index..html, but it doesn't render... Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I also used the WebIDE to sim your problem. Turns out the buttons are "cozy" (optimised for smaller screens). In my plunkr there is a method that sets the density depending on the device type. Will update my answer.

Comment: even though it forgot it for the replica in the webide, i did set it in my actual app. but through fiddeling with it I at least found the problem. In compact mode it works just fine, but on cozy devices i have the problem. every controll is on cozy but the select is still in compact mode. Now that I know the root of the problem I will update the question

Comment: Don't ask me why but there is special CSS for some controls when placed in the ObjectPageHeader. Not sure why not all controls are affected. Also cozy is the default so I guess it doesn't really help adding `sapUiSizeCozy` directly to the `Select`. Good look!